# How to handle all the characters in Vec<u8>?

Tags: rust, vec

I am using vec to storing the string data on the chain.

So when any user passing few special character it just convert it into the binary data and storing that binary data on the chain. Which we cannot decode later.

List of character on which this issue happening:

- Latin charcters - ñ
- Single apostrophe (unclosed) - ‘
- Emojis
- %0A - This represents a line feed or newline character.
- %20 - This represents a space character when URL-encoded.

Is there any way to handle these data to store on the chain? or do we have any other type to store string data on chain?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In low-level `String` is `Vec`, `Vec` is `String`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#365-367

You must instruct your library or dApp on how to handle this data when it reads these from storages.